# Finding circle in binary image (R, not matlab)

Tags: image-processing, noise, r

How would I extract the circular area of a binary image which looks like:

[image]

The two rods emerging from the side of the circle are noise.

I know of the hough transform in Matlab. However, I am using R and can't seem to find anything similar.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: This is an R specific question, and I think you're going to get a better response on Stack Overflow. Should I migrate it?

Comment: I guess it has a bit of both. Sure though

Answer (score -1):

On page 4 of [this document](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PET/PET.pdf) describing the R PET package, there's documentation of the Hough transformation. That's probably what you want.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how to use this for detection of circles

Comment: How to call the function or how to install it?

Comment: I understand how to do both. The returned data is a matrix of parameters of the the original matrix. Am I correct? How do I use that to approximate circles in the image